# Using javascript_include_tag with a Subfolder full of JS

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a bunch of Javascripts in a folder under `/public/javascripts/test` and I want to include them in my layout using `javascript_include_tag` in as few lines as possible.

Currently I have 25 lines of code using `javascript_include_tag`, is there any way to do this better? Also I cannot use `javascript_include_tag :all :recursive` since there are some JS files in other directories that I do not want included.

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**
So now I have a javascript.rb initializer that has this single line of code (very long):

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.register_javascript_expansion :syntax_highlight => Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/sh/*.js"].each {|js| js.gsub!("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/",'')}
```

Now in my layout I have the follwing:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :syntax_highlight %>
```

Now when I render the page I get the following:

```
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shAutoloader.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushAppleScript.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushAS3.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushBash.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushColdFusion.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushCpp.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushCSharp.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushCss.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushDelphi.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushDiff.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushErlang.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushGroovy.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushJava.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushJavaFX.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushJScript.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushPerl.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushPhp.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushPlain.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushPowerShell.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushPython.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushRuby.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushSass.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushScala.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushSql.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushVb.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shBrushXml.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shCore.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/sh/shLegacy.js?1278089940" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But for some reason none of this works? What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there's even better solution for that, but this will still do the trick:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/test/*.js"].each {|js_file| javascript_include_tag js_file }
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work... It causes the page to render really weird - the string of javascripts ends up within <body>

Answer (score 1):

try this

In config/application.rb

uncomment this line

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(javascript1.js javascript2.js)
```

and add the names of the files, like javascrip1.js and javascrip2t.js and so on.

Then in views/layouts add this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Vlad Khomich's answer is also great and will work.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are including so many js files, I am assuming, that you want to include all the js files under public directory. If this is the case, you can change in your [javascript_include_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag) as following, it will help you serve the whole file as one in production, saving lots of requests:

```
javascript_include_tag :all, :recursive => true, :cache => true
```

If you want to treat the test files saperately, you can [register_javascript_expansion](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-c-register_javascript_expansion), like `:defaults`, and also use the code from Vlad Khomich's answer.

```
# config/init/javascript.rb
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.register_javascript_expansion :tests => [array_of_js_paths_from_previous_answer]

# application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :tests, :cache => :tests %>
```