# ExecJS::RuntimeError in rails 3.2.8 engine with javascript_include_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, execjs

We are putting two rails 3.2.8 engines together in one rails app. The problem is that ExecJS does not like namespace for javascript_inclide_tag in layouts file. Here is the tag which causing the error:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'authentify/application' %>
```

Here authentify is rails engine name. The error is:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Authentify/sessions#new 
Showing C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/authentify/app/views/layouts/sessions.html.erb where line #6 raised: 

  (in C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/authentify/app/assets/javascripts/authentify/sessions.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6): 
3: <head>
4:   <title>Login</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "authentify/application" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "authentify/application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9:
```

If we delete the namespace authentify (`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`), then the ExecJS error disappears and the rails app works. There is the same error for another rails engine with the js tag.

We are using windows environment. What could cause the error? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

In engine.rb for authentify, every js libraries are listed as:

```
initializer "Authentify precompile hook", :group => :all do |app|
      app.config.assets.precompile += [
        'authentify/application.css.scss', 'authentify/layout.css.scss', 'authentify/login.css.scss', 
        'authentify/paginate.css.scss', 'authentify/sessions.css.scss', 'authentify/sys_logs.css.scss', 
        'authentify/toolbar.css.scss', 'authentify/user_level_group_map.css', 'authentify/user_menus.css.scss', 
        'authentify/users.css.scss', 'authentify/application.js', 'authentify/sessions.js.coffee', 
        'authentify/sys_logs.js.coffee', 'authentify/user_level_group_map.js', 'authentify/user_menus.js.coffee', 
        'authentify/users.js']

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Using javascript_include_tag with a Subfolder full of JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948182/using-javascript-include-tag-with-a-subfolder-full-of-js)

Can you have an initializer for each engine? In which case you could have:

Initializer for one (call it `authentify`) - e.g. authentify.rb as one initializer for engine A:

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.register_javascript_expansion :authentify => Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/authentify/*.js"].each {|js| js.gsub!("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/",'')}
```

Initializer for the other (call it `authentify2`) - e.g. authentify2.rb as one initializer for engine B:

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.register_javascript_expansion :authentify2 => Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/authentify2/*.js"].each {|js| js.gsub!("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/javascripts/",'')}
```

and then you can have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :authentify %>
```

in one layout and:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :authentify2 %>
```

in the other, and just remove the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'authentify/application' %>` in your layout as well as the other `javascript_include_tag` tag for your other engine.

Comment: Just updated the post with initializer in engine.rb. Do you mean two initializers for engine authentify? Also can you explain more about your answer? We don't know much about the js tag other than including js libraries. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Edited - is this clearer? Not sure how you are running your 2 rails engines in parallel, they must be picking up config from somewhere? If so, put 1 initializer rb file under one config and the other initializer rb file under the other config.

Comment: We just mount two rails engine in one rails app. Thanks.

Comment: created js_init.rb under engine authentify's config/initializers with the line above and it worked. Can you explain why removing the partial js path solves the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that execjs does not work on windows 8. Here is a [post](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/81) about how to go into the execjs runtimes and fix it on windows 8.

Comment: Thanks, this link led me to the right place. pottsk's [workaround](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/81#issuecomment-9892952) did the trick for me.